# Suppress login details in error log for Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap_connect()

Tags: php

While adding functionality to authenticate via LDAP to a PHP application, I noted the following error in the PHP error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
```

The remainder of the error text includes `Stack trace` which includes information about a call to function `authorise` - including the parameters passed, which means the supplied username and password are displayed in plain text in the error log. This is pretty surprising.

Can I suppress the display of login details in the error log without suppressing the whole error message?

That is, of course I still want to know if ldap_connect is undefined - but without displaying user credentials at the same time.

PHP 7.2.7 on IIS.

EDIT: Additional info follows, in response to Obsidian Age's answer.

I subsequently put my ldap_connect call within a `try`/`catch` block, viz:

```
try {

    $ds=ldap_connect($ldapServer);

    // bunch of other code

 } catch(Exception $e) {

    echo 'Damn.';
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    var_dump($e->getTrace());

}
```

Despite this, nothing is echoed to screen and the error log output looks the same as before adding this change.

Even with the `try`/`catch` block, the log describes an uncaught error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
```

The line number points to the `ldap_connect` call within the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

**[`ldap_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php)** is undefined because you don't have the the LDAP module installed. Specifically, you're missing `php_ldap.dll` You should be able to install this file directly through PHP Manager (which can be installed through IIS). If that doesn't work, the file can be downloaded manually, and the reference can be added directly to `php.ini`.

As for hiding your passwords in the stack traces, you can hook into the **[`Exception::getTrace()`](http://php.net/manual/tr/exception.gettrace.php)** method to get the information, and write a custom **[`getTraceAsString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php)** which doesn't include the relevant parameters:

```
function CustomException(Exception $e) {
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    // Change the output
    return $trace;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Please see my updated question - I tried the `catch`/`try` block - and adding some functions to view the trace (to check this approach is working) but no change to error log.